# How to serve files to download from HTML using django templating

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm stuck in my project where i want to serve some files to download on clicking the download button on my webpage.
Can anyone kindly direct me how to serve downloadable files on the web pages using template in django.

in normal html, we can achieve as

```
  <a href="<path_of_file>" download>
```

I am beginner in django. need some assistance with django templating

Generally, to render the dictionary text "{{ inser_me }}" in HTML and i created the entry in **"views.py"** as below.

```
def index(request):
    my_dict = {'insert_me':"Now I am coming from first_app/index.html!"}
    return render(request,'app/index.html',context=my_dict)
```

I saw about media file handling and added the below in **"settings.py"**

MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

and I put the contents under media directory. I can able to download the file if I use as **"http://localhost/media/file_name"**

can you please advise how i need to instruct in **views.py** to access this url.

```
 <a href="{{ ?? }}" download>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace  with the file url in your template:

```
  <a href="{{ my_file.url }}" download>
```

Comment: Hi henderikschneider, Thanks for your support I updated my question more elaborate, kindly assist me in handling the template in views.py to grab the file under media directory

Comment: @narenviru Can you please also post your that is used in the view

Comment: I solved it just a simple solution.. as you said I used file url directly by using in HTML as.                                                                
              <a href="{{ "media/filename.docx" }}" download>

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: You are welcome :) Would you mind to accept the answer :)